# Rails as web service: store data as json hash vs activerecord entities

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, client-server

I'm creating an iOS app with a Rails server to store and sync user information across devices.

Just as an example, let's say my user has an email to uniquely identify himself and a list of places:

```
{
    email: ...,
    places: [
        {
            id: ...,
            name: ...,
            latitude: ...,
            longitude: ...,
            category: ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In my iOS app I have the `User` and `Place` entities/classes.

Should I also have a `Place` activerecord entity in Rails with the parameters (name, latitude, longitude, category) in the migration or should I just have a `Place` entity with `id` and `data`, `data` being a hash that would contain the keys "name", "latitude", "longitude" and "category"?

One advantage I see with the second approach is that if I update my models in the iOS App, I don't have to also update it in the Rails server, because it is only storing a hash for each place.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends:

- on how often you need to update the information in the hash
- whether you will be updating just one item or all the data in the hash
- what database or other storage you want to use
- whether this data needs to be searchable by attribute or just by id

I think you'll be able to see what will direct your decision.

One thing to note about the apparent flexibility of using JSON stored as a   document, and having that avoid needing to update schemas as requirements change, is you must be very much more careful that your server and app can handle unexpected variations in the JSON structure and data completeness. With a relational database you gain some sense of structure and control that is lost when you allow arbitrary JSON to be used. This is fine, but you must take care to handle unexpected missing or additional data more carefully throughout your architecture.

There is much more that could be said, but this is my take on your request.

Comment: Let's say I don't care about performance right now, and that my server will mainly be used for syncing only, so not much logic there except check timestamps to see which data is more recent. Which approach would you use in that case?

Comment: If you are assuming that the requirements for adding logic won't change, with simple document storage to save and subsequently load the latest version then you are probably looking at a classic noSQL requirement. People love MongoDB. I'm a big fan of ElasticSearch as it provides flexible JSON searching for future requirements. Postgres has some JSON capabilities too, if you eventually want to index certain JSON attributes, and can use the standard relational stuff too. We all have our favored tools. I'd pick based on scalability requirements probably.